# Why does my println in rdd prints the string of elements?

Tags: scala, apache-spark

When I try to print the contents of my RDD, it prints something like displayed below, how can I print the content?
Thanks!

```
scala> lines
res15: org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[Array[String]] = MapPartitionsRDD[3] at filter at <console>:23



scala> lines.take(5).foreach(println)

[Ljava.lang.String;@6d3db5d1
[Ljava.lang.String;@6e6be45e
[Ljava.lang.String;@6d5e0ff4
[Ljava.lang.String;@3a699444
[Ljava.lang.String;@69851a51
```

Answer (score 6):

This is because it uses the `toString` implementation for the given object. In this case `Array` prints out the type and hash. If you convert it to a `List` then it will be a prettier output due to `List`'s `toString` implementation

```
scala>println(Array("foo"))
[Ljava.lang.String;HASH    

scala>println(Array("foo").toList)
List(foo)
```

Comment: For me it prints `List([Ljava.lang.String;@59a6e353)`

Answer (score 4):

Depending on how you want to print them out you can change your line that prints the elements to:

```
scala> lines.take(5).foreach(indvArray => indvArray.foreach(println))
```