# how to print a rdd correctly

Tags: scala, apache-spark

excuse me, I'm a new learner of spark, now I want to print a rdd in a right format, but the result is like that:

```
(200412169,([Ljava.lang.String;@7515eb2d,[Ljava.lang.String;@72031368))
(200412169,([Ljava.lang.String;@7515eb2d,[Ljava.lang.String;@27ef4b52))
```

my rdd is

```
Array[(String, (Array[String], Array[String]))] =
  Array(
    (200412169,(Array(gavin),Array(1, 24, 60, 85, 78))), 
    (200412169,(Array(gavin),Array(2, 22, 20, 85, 78))), 
    (200412166,(Array(gavin3),Array(1, 54, 80, 78, 98))), 
  )
```

and I want to print it like that:

```
200412169       gavin   2       22      20      85      78
200412169       gavin   1       24      60      85      78
```

is someone can help me, thanks very much.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my println in rdd prints the string of elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33680647/why-does-my-println-in-rdd-prints-the-string-of-elements)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The odd-looking print is the result of calling `toString` on a Java Array. To get a nice tab-separated printout, you can map each record into a String formatted to your liking, something like:

```
rdd.map { case (a, (arr1, arr2)) => (a +: arr1) ++ arr2 } // "flatten" into single array
  .map(_.mkString("\t")) // combine into Tab-separated string
  .foreach(println)

// 200412166    gavin3  1   54  80  78  98
// 200412169    gavin   2   22  20  85  78
// 200412169    gavin   1   24  60  85  78
```

Alternatively, if you do want to keep the RDD's structure, just see a proper representation of it when printing, you can simply convert the Arrays (with their not-so-useful toString) with Scala Lists:

```
rdd.map { case (a, (arr1, arr2)) => (a, arr1.toList, arr2.toList) }
  .foreach(println)

// (200412169,List(gavin),List(1, 24, 60, 85, 78))
// (200412166,List(gavin3),List(1, 54, 80, 78, 98))
// (200412169,List(gavin),List(2, 22, 20, 85, 78))
```

Answer (score 1):

You are viewing the result `(200412169,([Ljava.lang.String;@7515eb2d,[Ljava.lang.String;@72031368))` 
is only because its calling `tostring` but in Scala to view the result of `RDD`you have to use `mkString` .

If you want to view the content of a RDD, one way is to use `collect()`

```
myRDD.collect().foreach(println)
```

when the RDD has more of lines use `take()` to just print few .

```
myRDD.take(n).foreach(println)
```

Example:

```
val input=sc.parallelize(List(1,2,3,4,5))
print(input.collect().mkString(","))
```

Result:
[image]